# What is the upper bound of BigInteger with character array implementation?

Tags: c++, memory, numbers

If I impement `BigInteger` with a character array (in C++), in terms of power of 10, what is my upper bound in a 32bit system?

In other words,

`- 10^x < N <= 10^x`

(first character is reserved for sign).

What is `x` in 32 bit system?

Please ignore for now that we have reserved memory for OS and consider all 4GB memory is addressable by us.

Comment: The size of the classes/structs involved matter: can you tell us them?

Comment: To be clear: you want to know how big a range you can represent w/ a single 4GB variable?  And what does it being a 32bit system have to do with anything (other than how you got the 4GB cap)?

Comment: There's no need to use a full character to represent sign if you simply use two's complement. Or do you mean that each digit (as opposed to each byte) is stored as a character? That's a very silly way to implement "`BigInteger`".

Comment: Silly yes, sure. But its a theoratical question. 

@black assume 0.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes. 32 bit because I want to hold it in memory and keep it all addressable. 4GB because that's the cap for a 32-bit system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 8-bit byte can hold 2<sup>8</sup>, or 256 unique values.

4GB of memory is 2<sup>32</sup>, or 4294967296 **bytes**.

Or 4294967295, if we subtract the one byte that you want to reserve for a sign

That's 34359738360 **bits**.

This many bits can hold 2<sup>34359738360</sup> unique values.

> `- 10^x < N <= 10^x`
>
> (first character is reserved for sign).
>
> What is x in 32 bit system?

[Wolfram Alpha suggests](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E4294967295%29) `- 10^1292913986 < N <= 10^1292913986` as the largest representable powers of 10.

So x is 1,292,913,986.

Comment: Sounds about right. Thought so too, but will wait a while to get some more answers rolling in before I accept yours. Thanks :)

Comment: It is not clear if you want a single digit (base 10) in a byte or not. If so, first line of this answer should be "An 8-bit byte can hold 10 unique values"

Answer (score 1):

`(−(2^(n−1))) to (2^(n−1) − 1)` calculates the range of a signed integer where `n` is the number of bits.[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types)

Assuming your referring to the whole 4GB of memory being allocated, that is 2<sup>32</sup>  (4,294,967,295) addressable bytes in 32 bit memory space, which is 2<sup>35</sup>  (34,359,738,368) bits.

Put that into the formula at the start and you get a range of - (2<sup>2<sup>35</sup>-1</sup>) to 2<sup>2<sup>35</sup>-1</sup> -1

This is assuming you use a bit for a sign, instead of a whole byte. If your going a use a whole byte for sign, you should calculate the unsigned range of 2<sup>35</sup>-8 bits. Which is from 0 to 2<sup>2<sup>35</sup>-8</sup>−1

According to [this](http://www.decodedscience.com/how-to-convert-the-base-of-an-exponent-with-logarithms/18524/2) page, to convert from an exponent of base 2 to an exponent of base 10, you should use the formula x = m*ln(2)/ln(10),where you are converting from 2<sup>m</sup> to 10 <sup>x</sup>.

Therefore, your answer is that the upper bound is 10<sup><sup>2<sup>35</sup>-8</sup>*ln(2)/ln(10)</sup>. I'm not going to even attempt to change that exponent into a decimal value.

Comment: I would like the value of ```x``` in power of 10 please.

Comment: Yeah I finished the answer.